# Zend - New Session every minute

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I'm using Zend Framework for PHP and handling sessions with the Zend_Session module. I noticed that there was a high number of session files being created, even though I'm pretty much the only one using it during development. There are currently two Zend sites running on the same server, so I decided to change the session file location temporary to another directory to only see the files created by my site.

I'm noticing that every minute, a new session file is being created, no matter what I do. Even when I log out or close the browser, there is still always one created every minute, at the moment, always exactly 11 seconds after the minute. When I do navigate my site and use features, 1 or 2 other session files get created which is normal.

Before I changed the location of the session files, at times the number of session files would increase by like 5 almost every few seconds, going from a total of like 200 session files to sometimes around 3 thousand. I have no idea if this is normal behavior for Zend or not, but I find it very strange.

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is my application.ini file. The commented out line is what I did to temporary change the default location to view only the sessions from my application.

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
phpSettings.date.timezone = "America/Montreal"
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutpath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.view.helperPath.App_View_Helper_ = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
;resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/tmp/TestSessions/"

appnamespace = "Application"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "HTMLPurifier"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "ZC"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "ZendX"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

**EDIT 2**

I got access to the 'access.log' file, and I discovered this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2014:15:08:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6356 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2014:15:09:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6356 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2014:15:10:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6356 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2014:15:11:11 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6356 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2014:15:12:11 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6356 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2014:15:13:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6356 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2014:15:14:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6356 "-" "-"
```

Apparently it's been going on since November of last year. I did a search in the file, and since November, it's been requested by 127.0.0.1 over 170 thousand times. The time it gets called at changes slightly over time, but always once a minute. (I also see the requests of the other people using the site including myself.)

Comment: @doydoy44 I edited my original question to include my application.ini file.

Comment: Check your access logs to see who/what is hitting your application and where.  Maybe there is a cron job running or some other process that is loading your page.  The sessions are only created if your application is being accessed, and new sessions would only be created if whatever client hitting your site does not send session cookies, hence a new session being started each request.

Comment: @drew010 I'm waiting for my co-worker to get back, he has root access and will be able to check the access logs. Until then, I did more testing and it seems you might be on to something. Still trying to figure out what and why though..

Comment: Edited my original question again to include part of my 'access.log' file.

Comment: Since its coming from 127.0.0.1 its something on the local server.  Check cron tabs for root and any other user to see if there is anything there, or look at what processes are running to figure if there is some sort of utility that attempts to hit the local server and see if it is up or down.  I'm not personally aware of something that may be automatically set to hit localhost once every 60 seconds.  You might temporarily change the http server to log the user agent since that may give you an extra hint.  Either way, that utility isn't keeping track of cookies which is why so many sessions

Comment: Thanks for your input drew010! I tried to find the source of the problem, but couldn't find anything except I know for sure it's not a cron job running. I tried doing what you said, about 'temporarily changing the http server to log the user agent since that may give you an extra hint' but I was unable to figure out how to do so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

In your application, add a directory `APPLICATION_PATH "/../tmp"`

add in production:

```
resources.session.use_cookies = true
resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
resources.session.use_trans_sid = off
resources.session.strict = off
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 0
resources.session.name = "YourNameSession"
resources.session.gc_divisor = 1000
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 600
resources.session.gc_probability = 1
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../tmp"
```

add in developemnt:

```
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 0
resources.session.gc_divisor = 10
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 8600
resources.session.gc_probability = 1
```

I'm not an expert in session.
If this example resolve your problem, research on Google the explanation of these parameters and adapt them.

Comment: Thanks doydoy44, I tried what you said, but it still creates that session every minute anyways. But using what you gave me, I changed the values and made it so the the garbage collector would run 100% of the time, and set the maxlife to 59 seconds. By doing this, I noticed that what @drew010 said might actually be the reason. When the new session appears every minute, the garbage collector goes off, meaning that something really does seem to be requesting my page every minute. Still trying to figure out what and why though..

Comment: @Brendan Thanks for your return. I also agree with drew010.If i've an other idea, i'll put it. good luck. :)